# Can I put a eb extension container command on multiple lines and if I can how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

All I've found about this is: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=112988

I know that I can do this:

```
container_commands:
   07_run_command:
      "mkdir -p /var/cache/tomcat8/temp/.m2/repository && chmod 777"
```

But can I do this?

```
container_commands:
   07_run_command:
      mkdir -p /var/cache/tomcat8/temp/.m2/repository && 
      chmod 777
```

And do I still need the && to separate the commands or are they executed as separate commands? or is it still only one command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done via YAML's literal block scalar, as follows:

```
container_commands:
  07_run_command: |
      mkdir -p /var/cache/tomcat8/temp/.m2/repository
      chmod 777
```

More documentation on the same can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands-options

Comment: thanks... that is a very nifty solution.

I went with a multi line command ala (separated by ;) - (\n = line feed as you can't have line feeds in comments)
07_run_command: \n
      mkdir -p /var/cache/tomcat8/temp/.m2/repository; \n
      chmod 777 \n but this solution is far more elegant.